# How to control MUI ClickAway

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, click

I have 2 child components [`MyTable`, `EditJobModal`] in a parent page. The `MyTable` uses the Material UI `DataGrid` and has `Clickaway` to deselect a row when the user clicks outside of the table/grid. I also use it to clear stored value in a hook. My problem is that after the modal, `EditJobModal`, is launched and I click on my `Submit` button in the modal, it fires the `ClickAway` handler immediately and clears the data I need to send in my submit. How can I control when the `ClickAway` is fired and keep it from triggering inside my modal component?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { ClickAwayListener } from '@mui/base';
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const MyTable = ({columns, data, childToParent}) => {
    const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = useState([]);
    const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

    const handleClickAway = () => {
        setSelectionModel([]);
        setSelectedRows([{'id': ''}]);
        childToParent(selectedRows);
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ height: 600, width: '100%' }}>
            <ClickAwayListener
                onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
                <DataGrid
                    columns={columns}
                    rows={data}
                    pageSize={5}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
                    checkboxSelection={false}
                    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
                    selectionModel={selectionModel}

                    onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                        if (ids.length > 1) {
                            let selectionSet = new Set(selectionModel);
                            let result = ids.filter((s) => !selectionSet.has(s));
                            setSelectionModel(result);
                        } else {
                            let selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
                            console.log(selectedIDs);
                            let selectedRows = data.filter((row) =>
                                selectedIDs.has(row.id),
                             );
                            setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
                            setSelectionModel(ids[0]);
                            childToParent(selectedRows);
                        }              
                    }}
                />
            </ClickAwayListener> 
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyTable;
```